# "It's useless worrying about it." VS "It's useless to worry about it."

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

(1) It's useless **worrying** about it.

(2) It's useless **to worry** about it.

**Question:** A Japanese teacher of English explains that (1) implies that the interlocutor is actually worrying about it, but (2) has no such implication. Is this explanation correct?

Comment: As an educated native speaker, I would say that the teacher is inaccurate. Although we often use the present continuous form about events or actions that are happening at the time, both sentences can be used in either of those situations, and others. The first in perhaps _slightly_ more natural in situation (1). This question may be considered off-topic for being a matter of opinion.

Comment: I agree with @MichaelHarvey in the sense that they’d both have the same meaning to me, and that the first one sounds more natural.

Comment: You can say either of those things (1) as advice to someone who is worrying about something at that time, or who might in the future, or (2) as a general statement about the uselessness of anyone, present or not, worrying about that thing at any time.

Comment: In any case, the present continuous form, i.e. 'he is worrying' is not what we have in the first sentence. What we have is the noun form, or gerund, ('worrying').

Answer (score 1):

Both of these sentences have approximately the same meaning. "worrying (about it)" and "to worry (about it)" are noun forms (gerund and infinitive respectively). As already answered in the comments by Michael Harvey, they could be used (1) as advice to someone who is worrying about something at that time, or who might in the future, or (2) as a general statement about the uselessness of anyone, present or not, worrying about that thing at any time.

There is some *implication* that the interlocutor is actually worrying about it, because otherwise you wouldn't say such a sentence. However the implication is not absolute. It might just be general advice.

A couple of comments suggested the first sentence sounds more natural. My first reaction was the second sentence sounds more natural. As a curiosity, If you flip the order around:

Worrying about it is useless.  (Good)
To worry about it is useless.  (more stilted)